# Keep task running between views React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, react-router-redux

I am developing this audio player app for iOS and after that will be ported to Android too and up until now everything is working fine, untill I got to the point that I had to implement the background play of audio. So basically if I'm switching between different views I have to keep the audio playing. I did a research on that but have not found an answer yet. It's more like keeping a task running in background, so if I am switching between views that task would not be stopped. I've seen some questions related to this one but they werent specifically related between keeping a task running on different views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about the background task nature of what you're looking at. It is definitely something that should be decoupled from the view. I'd recommend setting up a new module that deals with music management in isolation. Have it export public *play* and *stop* methods. Then in your root React Component file *require* that module and invoke *play* and *stop* in your *componentWillMount* and *componentWillUnmount* methods. Thus your sound won't be coupled to a specific component and persists while switching views.

This looks like an adequate library to help you with playback:
https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound